# Grammar - has or have

Tags: grammar

Which of the two following texts below are grammatically correct.

"The Board finds that **both** the identity of the member and the facts surrounding the alleged conduct **has** been proven on a balance of probabilities."

"The Board finds that the identity of the member and the facts surrounding the alleged conduct **have** been proven on a balance of probabilities."

Comment: Not the first version.

Answer (score 1):

The one with have is correct. You can leave out both, or keep it in. The first sentence would be correct if has were replaced with have.

This is because the subject, two things, is plural.
An example to illustrate this:

```
I don't like Jim, nor David, they **are** so annoying.
I don't like Jim, nor David, both of them **are** so annoying.
I don't like Jim, nor David, they **are** both so annoying.
```

Comment: Another possibility would be to say "I don't like Jim, nor David, they both are so annoying." :-)